# Languages other than English in iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect, mac-app-store

We have an app in the US app store, which we want our users to be able to find in Hebrew as well. so we want them to be able to search for the app name in English or Hebrew and still find it.
Turns out entering keywords in Hebrew doesn't work, ie searching for these keywords in Hebrew in the US store returns no results.
Does the US not support search in Hebrew, or do we need to add Hebrew as a language in the app's metadata in iTunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the appStore (in your case US) will of course only bring results in that language (English for now).
If you want it to be available in Hebrew then you will have to put it into the related appStore, while you don't have to translate you whole app into Hebrew except you want your users to have that translation as well.

Hope I could help ;)